# Convert a list from data frame (emmGrid class)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to convert a list to dataframe (picture as below)

I did use `do.call(rbind.data.frame, contrast)`, however,  I got this `Error in xi[[j]] : this S4 class is not subsettable`. I still can read them separately. Anyone know about this thing?

This list I got when running the ART anova test by using the package `ARTool`

[image]

**Update**

This my orignial code to calculate and get the model done.

```
Organism_df_posthoc <- bird_metrics_long_new %>% 
  rbind(plant_metrics_long_new) %>% 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type, levels = c("Forest", "Jungle rubber", "Rubber", "Oil palm"))) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category)) %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("PD"), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  nest_by(n1) %>% 
  mutate(fit = list(art.con(art(PD ~ Category + Type + Category:Type, data = data), 
                                  "Category:Type",adjust = "tukey", interaction = T)))
```

And the output of `fit` is that I showed already.

Comment: Can you show the `dput(head(Organism_df_posthoc, 2))`

Comment: When I see 9 pipes in succession, I simply shut down and refuse to try to follow that many steps. Break it down into smaller steps and see what you get in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `rbind`, instead of `rbind.data.frame`, there is a specific method for 'emmGrid' object and it can directly use the correct method by matching the `class` if we specify just `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, contrast)
```

-output

```
wool tension emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    L         44.6 3.65 48     33.6     55.5
 A    M         24.0 3.65 48     13.0     35.0
 A    H         24.6 3.65 48     13.6     35.5
 B    L         28.2 3.65 48     17.2     39.2
 B    M         28.8 3.65 48     17.8     39.8
 B    H         18.8 3.65 48      7.8     29.8
 A    L         44.6 3.65 48     33.6     55.5
 A    M         24.0 3.65 48     13.0     35.0
 A    H         24.6 3.65 48     13.6     35.5
 B    L         28.2 3.65 48     17.2     39.2
 B    M         28.8 3.65 48     17.8     39.8
 B    H         18.8 3.65 48      7.8     29.8

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 12 estimates
```

The reason is that there is a specific method for `rbind` when we load the `emmeans`

```
> methods('rbind')
[1] rbind.data.frame  rbind.data.table* rbind.emm_list*   rbind.emmGrid*    rbind.grouped_df* rbind.zoo*
```

The structure in the example created matches the OP's structure showed

[image]

By using `rbind.data.frame`, it doesn't match because the class is already `emmGrid`

#### data

```
library(multcomp)
library(emmeans)


warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool*tension, data = warpbreaks)

warp.emmGrid <- emmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension | wool)
contrast <- list(warp.emmGrid, warp.emmGrid)
```

---

If the OP used 'ARTool' and if the columns are different, the above solution may not work because `rbind` requires all objects to have the same column names.  We could convert to `tibble` by looping over the `list` with `map` (from `purrr`) and bind them

```
library(ARTool)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map_dfr(contrast, as_tibble)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 42 × 8
   contrast estimate    SE    df t.ratio  p.value Moisture_pairwise Fertilizer_pairwise
   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>             <fct>              
 1 m1 - m2    -23.1   4.12  8.00  -5.61  0.00226  NA                NA                 
 2 m1 - m3    -33.8   4.12  8.00  -8.20  0.000169 NA                NA                 
 3 m1 - m4    -15.2   4.12  8.00  -3.68  0.0256   NA                NA                 
 4 m2 - m3    -10.7   4.12  8     -2.59  0.118    NA                NA                 
 5 m2 - m4      7.92  4.12  8      1.92  0.291    NA                NA                 
 6 m3 - m4     18.6   4.12  8      4.51  0.00849  NA                NA                 
 7 NA           6.83 10.9  24      0.625 0.538    m1 - m2           f1 - f2            
 8 NA          15.3  10.9  24      1.40  0.174    m1 - m3           f1 - f2            
 9 NA          -5.83 10.9  24     -0.533 0.599    m1 - m4           f1 - f2            
10 NA           8.50 10.9  24      0.777 0.445    m2 - m3           f1 - f2            
# … with 32 more rows
```

#### data

```
data(Higgins1990Table5, package = "ARTool")
m <- art(DryMatter ~ Moisture*Fertilizer + (1|Tray), data=Higgins1990Table5)
a1 <- art.con(m, ~ Moisture)
a2 <- art.con(m, "Moisture:Fertilizer", interaction = TRUE)
contrast <- list(a1, a2)
```

Comment: I got this `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :   All objects must have the same fixed effects`

Comment: @Anh can you show your code.  I was thinking that you used `emmeans`

Comment: I just updated my question. Please look at it!

Comment: @Anh did you install the `ARTtool` from `github`. I tried to install from CRAN, but the package is not available for the version

Comment: oh sorry the package without small `t`. `ARTool`

Comment: @Anh I tried with 'ARTool', my solution is working though (updated).  It may be because you have a specific case which I couldn't reproduce.  Can you update with a reprodcuible example

Comment: it was so weird. I used only 2 first elements of my list. and still now working. I am thinking it might be caused by the model i am using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238733/discussion-between-anh-and-akrun).

Comment: @Anh I was able to replicate.  Please check my update now